Unable to streamUI components correctly using Vercel's AI-SDK
I have been trying to learn the new Vercel's AI-SDK.
I'm trying to create a persona generator which takes in certain guidelines as inputs and then generates a persona attributes in a given Zod schema.
This is the function I'm using in my actions.tsx file
export async function personaSchemaGeneration(context: string) {
    'use server';
  
    const stream = createStreamableValue();
  
    (async () => {
      const { partialObjectStream } = await streamObject({
        model: openai('gpt-3.5-turbo'),
        system: 'You generate a persona basis the brand context.',
        prompt: 'Generate a persona for the brand in line with the following context: ' + context,
        schema: personaSchema,
      });
  
      for await (const partialObject of partialObjectStream) {
        stream.update(partialObject);
      }
  
      stream.done();
    })();
  
    return { object: stream.value };
  }

This returns a text stream in the correct format that I can display on the screen in my onClick function over here.
const { object } = await personaSchemaGeneration(brandContext);
          
          for await (const partialObject of readStreamableValue(object)) {
            console.log("Partial Obj",partialObject, "    ", object)
            if (partialObject) {
              setGeneration(
                JSON.stringify(partialObject, null, 2),
              );
            }
          }
          console.log("Final Obj",object)

I want to ideally return the UI using streamUI which is what I was trying to do (unsuccessfully) with this function.
export async function personaSchemaGenerationUI(context: string) {
    'use server';

    const result = await streamUI({
        model: openai('gpt-3.5-turbo'),
        system: 'You generate a persona basis the brand context.',
        prompt: 'Generate a persona for the brand in line with the following context: ' + context,
        schema: personaSchema,
        text:({ content }) => <Persona3 {...content} />
        ,
        },
      );
    
      return result.value;
  }

I'm struggling to get to grips with a few things

When I'm trying to read the object that has been returned once the text stream is completed I get this. Whereas my understanding is that the function personaSchemaGeneration() should return a personaSchema type that I have defined. What am I doing wrong? 


Having gone through some of the examples over here https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/ai-sdk-rsc/streaming-react-components I gather that we can return UI components and have an intermediary loading component shown through yield. However, in my function personaSchemaGenerationUI() I don't want to use any tool instead just want to pass the output from the LLM that is in the personaSchema format to the React Component which I can display to the user. I'm not able to understand why the content is not being correctly passed into the Persona file or being returned to the user

This is more of a general question.
a) Are we only allowed to return one component as part of the streamUI function? If I want to stream multiple components say 10 different personas would I have to create 10 different async function calls and load each of them independently or is there a smarter way to do that?
b) Are we allowed to call only 1 tool as part of the streamUI functions? I have tried to add in another tool definition but it always seem to default to the first one even when I change the description of the tool.


Thanks in advance for your help! Been stuck with this for a while now and not sure what I seem to be doing wrong or where the gaps in my knowledge are...

As you want to generate your personas from a user input, I think streamUI is better suited.
For your second question:
What you did when calling streamUI is right, but I think you're missing one point. The streamUI method won't render anything and must be used alongside your UiState and AiState.
You're messages have to be rendered from the UiState (accessible on client side through useUIState hook) and the state should be updated each time a user inputs something, or when your streamUi promise is fulfilled:
const [conversation, setConversation] = useUIState();
const message = await continueConversation(input);

setConversation((currentConversation: ClientMessage[]) => [
   ...currentConversation,
   message,
]);

You can find an example of how it works here
For your third question:
a) What I would do to achieve that, is that I would use a tool dedicated to persona creation (using for example a zod schema containing your 10 personas as properties) and then I would return each of the personas in the streamUi response as a single react component.
(There is probably a more elegant way to achieve this, but I think it should work great.)
b)There is a feature called parallel tools call but I don't think it can be used with streamUi.
Ps: feel free to tell If you want me to add a sandbox showing a working example of your persona project using streamUi.
